# Userscript to tighten security in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, userscript, firefox

I have recently started writing a userscript for Mozilla Firefox to tighten security and make it more private, but before I want to start publishing it, I would like to have some experts take a look at it to see if I made any mistakes, I am by no means a experienced coder, and this is my first little project. Things I am looking for are tips to make my code easier to read and if I have any missing crypto suites (again if this is the wrong way to ask this then please feel free to correct me and say what I should say).

I will also post a link to the GitHub paste since its easier to read [there](https://github.com/blacklight447/blacklight447-s-firefox-privacy-userscript).

```js
// firefox privacy setup, last time edited: 5 10 2016 //


// geo switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("geo.enabled",                                        false);
user_pref("geo.wifi.logging.enabled",                           false);
user_pref("geo.wifi.uri", "http://127.0.0.1");


// media switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("media.peerconnection.ice.default_address_only"       true);
user_pref("media.peerconnection.enabled",          false);
user_pref("media.navigator.enabled",                            false);
user_pref("media.webspeech.recognition.enable",                 false);
user_pref("media.getusermedia.screensharing.enabled",  false);
user_pref("media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains",   "");
user_pref("media.eme.enabled",                                  false);
user_pref("media.eme.apiVisible",                               false);
user_pref("media.gmp-eme-adobe.enabled",                        false);
user_pref("media.video_stats.enabled",                          false);
user_pref("media.gmp-gmpopenh264.enabled",          false);
user_pref("media.gmp-manager.url",                  "");
user_pref("media.gmp-provider.enabled",                         false);
user_pref("media.peerconnection.turn.disable",                  true);
user_pref("media.peerconnection.use_document_iceservers",       false);
user_pref("media.peerconnection.video.enabled",                 false);
user_pref("media.peerconnection.identity.timeout",              false);
user_pref("media.autoplay.enabled",                             false);
user_pref("media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains",   "");

// device switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("device.sensors.enabled",                             false);


// camera switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("camera.control.face_detection.enabled",              false);
user_pref("camera.contro.autofocus_moving_callback.enabled",    false);


// devtool switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("devtools.webide.autoinstallADBHelper",               false);
user_pref("devtools.webide.autoinstallFxdtAdapters",            false);
user_pref("devtools.debugger.remote-enabled",                   false);
user_pref("devtools.webide.enabled",                            false);
user_pref("devtools.chrome.enabled",                            false);
user_pref("devtools.debugger.force-local",                      true);


// network switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("network.http.spdy.enabled",                          false); 
user_pref("network.http.spdy.enabled.v3",                       false);
user_pref("network.http.spdy.enabled.v3-1",                     false);
user_pref("network.http.spdy.enabled.http2",                    false);
user_pref("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns",                     true);
user_pref("network.jar.open-unsafe-types",          false);
user_pref("network.prefetch-next",                  false);
user_pref("network.dns.disablePrefetch",          true);
user_pref("network.dns.disablePrefetchFromHTTPS",  true);
user_pref("network.predictor.enabled",                          false);
user_pref("network.seer.enabled",                               false);
user_pref("network.http.speculative-parallel-limit",  0);
user_pref("network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1",      false);
user_pref("network.http.referer.spoofSource",                   true);
user_pref("network.cookie.cookieBehavior",                      2);
user_pref("network.cookie.thirdparty.sessionOnly",  true);
user_pref("network.cookie.lifetimePolicy",                      2);
user_pref("network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist",        true);
user_pref("network.http.sendSecureXSiteReferrer",               false);
user_pref("network.http.redirection-limit",                     10);
user_pref("network.http.sendSecureXSiteReferrer",               false);
user_pref("network.http.proxy.keep-alive",                      false);
user_pref("network.IDN_show_punycode",                          true);
user_pref("Network.cookie.p3p", "frfrarar");
user_pref("network.allow-experiments",                          false);


// plugin(s) switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("plugin.state.flash",                              0);
user_pref("plugin.state.libgnome-shell-browser-plugin",         0);
user_pref("plugins.click_to_play",                              true);
user_pref("plugins.update.notifyUser",                  true);
user_pref("plugins.hide_infobar_for_outdated_plugin",  false);
user_pref("plugin.scan.plid.all",                               false);
user_pref("plugin.scan.Acrobat",                                99999);
user_pref("plugin.scan.Quicktime",                              99999);
user_pref("plugin.scan.WindowsMediaPlayer",                     99999);
user_pref("plugin.default.state",                               0);
user_pref("plugin.defaultXpi.state",                            0);
user_pref("plugin.sessionPermissionNow.intervalInMinutes",      0);
user_pref("plugins.notifyMissingFlash",                         false);


// javascript //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("javascript.options.methodjit.chrome",  false);
user_pref("javascript.options.methodjit.content",  false);
user_pref("javascript.options.asmjs",                  false);
user_pref("javascript.enabled",                                 false);


// datareport switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("datareporting.healthreport.uploadEnabled",           false);
user_pref("datareporting.healthreport.service.enabled",         false);
user_pref("datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionEnabled",         false);
user_pref("datareporting.healthreport.documentServerURI",       "");
user_pref("datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionEnabled.v2",      false);
user_pref("datareporting.healthreport.about.reportUrl",         "");
user_pref("datareporting.healthreport.about.reportUrlUnified",  "");
user_pref("datareporting.healthreport.documentServerURI",       "");


// toolkit switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("toolkit.telemetry.enabled",                          false);
user_pref("toolkit.telemetry.unified",                          false);
user_pref("toolkit.telemetry.server",                           "");
user_pref("toolkit.telemetry.archive.enabled",                  false);
user_pref("toolkit.telemetry.rejected",                         true);
user_pref("toolkit.telemetry.prompted",                         2);
user_pref("toolkit.telemetry.cachedClientID",                   "");

// extension  switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled",                 false);
user_pref("extensions.update.enabled",                          true);
user_pref("extensions.blocklist.enabled",                       true);
user_pref("extensions.webservice.discoverURL",                  "http://127.0.0.1");

// experiment switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("experiments.supported",                  false);
user_pref("experiments.enabled",                  false);
user_pref("experiments.manifest.uri",                           "");
user_pref("experiments.activeExperiment",                       false);


// social switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("social.whitelist",                                   "");
user_pref("social.toast-notifications.enabled",                 false);
user_pref("social.shareDirectory",                              "");
user_pref("social.remote-install.enabled",                      false);
user_pref("social.directories",                                 "");
user_pref("social.share.activationPanelEnabled",                false);


// dom switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("dom.storage.enabled",                                false);
user_pref("dom.indexedDB.enabled",                              true);
user_pref("dom.webnotifications.enabled",                       false);
user_pref("dom.webnotifications.serviceworker.enabled",         false);
   user_pref("dom.disable_image_src_set",                true);
user_pref("dom.battery.enabled",                                false);
user_pref("dom.telephony.enabled",                              false);
user_pref("dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled",                  false);
user_pref("dom.enable_performance",                  false);
user_pref("dom.gamepad.enabled",                  false);
user_pref("dom.vibrator.enabled",                               false);
user_pref("dom.vr.enabled",                          false);
user_pref("dom.vr.oculus.enabled",                              false);
user_pref("dom.vr.oculus050.enabled",                           false);
user_pref("dom.netinfo.enabled",                                false);
user_pref("dom.network.enabled",                                false);
user_pref("dom.workers.sharedWorkers.enabled",                  false);
user_pref("dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled",                       0);
user_pref("dom.enable_resource_timing",                         false);
user_pref("dom.enable_user_timing",                             false);
user_pref("dom.idle-observers-api.enabled",                     false);
user_pref("dom.webnotifications.enabled",          false);
user_pref("dom.push.connection.enabled",                        false);
user_pref("dom.push.serverURL",                                 "");
user_pref("dom.push.udp.wakeupEnabled",                         false);
user_pref("dom.push.userAgentID",                               "");
user_pref("dom.push.enabled",                                   false);
user_pref("dom.disable_beforeunload",                           true);
user_pref("dom.push.enabled",                                   false);
user_pref("dom.event.contextmenu.enabled",                      false);
user_pref("dom.disable_window_open_feature.location",           true); 
user_pref("dom.disable_window_open_feature.menubar",            true);
user_pref("dom.disable_window_open_feature.resizable",          true);
user_pref("dom.disable_window_open_feature.scrollbars",         true);
user_pref("dom.disable_window_open_feature.status",             true);
user_pref("dom.disable_window_open_feature.toolbar",            true);
user_pref("dom.disable_window_flip",                            true); 
user_pref("dom.disable_window_move_resize",                     true);
user_pref("dom.disable_window_open_feature.close",              true);
user_pref("dom.disable_window_open_feature.minimizable",        true);
user_pref("dom.disable_window_open_feature.personalbar",        true); 
user_pref("dom.disable_window_open_feature.titlebar",           true);
user_pref("dom.disable_window_status_change",                   true);
user_pref("dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows",                 false);
user_pref("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled",                            false);
user_pref("dom.ipc.plugins.flash.subprocess.crashreporter.enabled", false);



// security switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("security.mixed_content.block_active_content",        true);
user_pref("security.mixed_content.block_display_content",       true);
user_pref("security.xpconnect.plugin.unrestricted",             false);
user_pref("security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy",              true);
user_pref("security.csp.experimentalEnabled",          true);
user_pref("security.csp.enable",                  true);
user_pref("security.sri.enable",                  true);
user_pref("security.mixed_content.block_active_content",        true);
user_pref("security.dialog_enable_delay",                       1000);


// security -crypto- switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("security.warn_entering_weak",          true);
user_pref("security.ssl.warn_missing_rfc5746",                  1);
user_pref("security.OCSP.enabled",                              1);
user_pref("security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling",          true);
user_pref("security.OCSP.require",                              true);
user_pref("security.enable_tls_session_tickets",                false);
user_pref("security.tls.version.min",                  3);
user_pref("security.tls.version.max",                  3);
user_pref("security.enable_ssl3",                               false);
user_pref("security.cert_pinning.enforcement_level",            2);
user_pref("security.pki.sha1_enforcement_level",                2);
user_pref("security.ssl.treat_unsafe_negotiation_as_broken",   true);
user_pref("security.ssl.errorReporting.automatic",              false);
user_pref("security.ssl.errorReporting.enabled",                false);
user_pref("security.ssl.errorReporting.url",                    "");
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_null_sha",                  false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_null_md5",                  false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_rsa_null_sha",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_ecdsa_null_sha",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdh_rsa_null_sha",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdh_ecdsa_null_sha",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_seed_sha",                  false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_rc4_40_md5",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_rc2_40_md5",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_1024_rc4_56_sha",                  false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_camellia_128_sha",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_rsa_aes_128_sha",  false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_sha",  false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdh_rsa_aes_128_sha",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdh_ecdsa_aes_128_sha",  false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_camellia_128_sha",  false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdh_ecdsa_rc4_128_sha",  false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdh_rsa_rc4_128_sha",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_ecdsa_rc4_128_sha",  false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_rsa_rc4_128_sha",  false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_rc4_128_md5",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_rc4_128_sha",          false);
user_pref("security.tls.unrestricted_rc4_fallback",  false);
user_pref("security.tls.insecure_safe_negotiation",             false);
user_pref("security.ssl.require_safe_negotiation",              true);
user_pref("security.ssl3.dhe_dss_des_ede3_sha",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_des_ede3_sha",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdh_ecdsa_des_ede3_sha",              false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdh_rsa_des_ede3_sha",         false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_ecdsa_des_ede3_sha",         false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_rsa_des_ede3_sha",         false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_des_ede3_sha",                 false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_fips_des_ede3_sha",  false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdh_rsa_aes_256_sha",          false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdh_ecdsa_aes_256_sha",         false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_camellia_256_sha",                 false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_rsa_aes_256_sha",         true);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_256_sha",         true);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_gcm_sha256", true);
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_rsa_aes_128_gcm_sha256",         true);
user_pref("security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_camellia_256_sha",         false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_256_sha",                 false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.dhe_dss_aes_128_sha",                 false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.dhe_dss_aes_256_sha",                 false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.dhe_dss_camellia_128_sha",             false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.dhe_dss_camellia_256_sha",         false);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_aes_256_sha",                 true);
user_pref("security.ssl3.rsa_aes_128_sha",                     true);


//  browser switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("browser.usedOnWindows10",                            false);
user_pref("browser.usedOnWindows10.introURL",                   "");
user_pref("browser.search.countryCode",                         "US");
user_pref("browser.search.region",                              "US");
user_pref("browser.download.manager.addToRecentDocs",           false);
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.enable",                          false);
user_pref("browser.cache.disk_cache_ssl",                       false);
user_pref("browser.cache.memory.enable",                        false);
user_pref("browser.history_expire_visits",                      0);
user_pref("browser.sessionstore.privacy_level",          2);
user_pref("browser.helperApps.deleteTempFileOnExit",         true);
user_pref("browser.pagethumbnails.capturing_disabled",          true);
user_pref("browser.download.useDownloadDir",          false);
user_pref("browser.sessionstore.postdata",                      0);
user_pref("browser.sessionstore.enabled",                       false);
user_pref("browser.cache.offline.enable",                       false);
user_pref("browser.aboutHomeSnippets.updateUrl",         "");
user_pref("browser.search.update",                         false);
user_pref("browser.search.suggest.enabled",                     false);
user_pref("browser.urlbar.suggest.searches",                    false);
user_pref("browser.casting.enabled",                  false);
user_pref("browser.search.geoip.url",                         "");
user_pref("browser.newtabpage.enhanced",                 false);
user_pref("browser.newtab.preload",                         false);
user_pref("browser.newtabpage.directory.ping",                  "");
user_pref("browser.newtabpage.directory.source",                "data:text/plain,{}");
user_pref("browser.selfsupport.url",                            "");
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.enabled",                       false);
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled",               false);
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.downloads.remote.enabled",      false);
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.reportMalwareMistakeURL",       "");
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.reportPhishMistakeURL",         "");
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.reportPhishURL",                "");
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.provider.google.appRepURL",     "");
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.provider.google.gethashURL",    "");
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.provider.google.reportURL",     "");
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.provider.google.updateURL",     "");
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.provider.mozilla.gethashURL",   "");
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.provider.mozilla.updateURL",    "");
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.downloads.enabled",             false);
user_pref("browser.safebrowsing.downloads.remote.enabled",      false);
user_pref("browser.display.use_document_fonts",                 0);
user_pref("browser.urlbar.filter.javascript",                 true);
user_pref("browser.send_pings",                                 false);
user_pref("browser.send_pings.require_same_host",         true);
user_pref("browser.fixup.alternate.enabled",                    false);
user_pref("browser.aboutHomeSnippets.updateUrl",                "https://127.0.0.1");
user_pref("browser.eme.ui.enabled",                             false);
user_pref("browser.download.manager.addToRecentDocs",           false); 
user_pref("browser.pagethumbnails.capturing_disabled",          true);
user_pref("browser.pagethumbnails.storage_version",             3);
user_pref("browser.casting.enabled",                            false);
user_pref("browser.sessionhistory.max_entries",                 2);
user_pref("browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction",            0);
user_pref("browser.search.geoSpecificDefaults",                 false);
user_pref("browser.trackingprotection.gethashURL",              "");
user_pref("browser.trackingprotection.getupdateURL",            "");
user_pref("browser.search.param.yahoo-fr",                      "");
user_pref("browser.search.param.yahoo-fr-ja",                   "");


//  font switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("font.name.serif.x-unicode",                          "Georgia");
user_pref("font.name.serif.x-western",                          "Georgia"); 
user_pref("font.name.sans-serif.x-unicode",                     "Arial");
user_pref("font.name.sans-serif.x-western",                     "Arial");  
user_pref("font.name.monospace.x-unicode",                      "Lucida Console");
user_pref("font.name.monospace.x-western",                      "Lucida Console"); 


// privacy switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("privacy.donottrackheader.enabled",                   true);
user_pref("privacy.donottrackheader.value",                     1); 
user_pref("privacy.trackingprotection.enabled",                 true);
user_pref("privacy.trackingprotection.pbmode.enabled",          false);

// webgl switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("webgl.disabled",                                     true);
user_pref("webgl.min_capability_mode",                          true);
user_pref("webgl.disable-extensions",                           true);


// gfx switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("gfx.font_rendering.opentype_svg.enabled",            false);
user_pref("gfx.downloadable_fonts.enabled",                     true);
user_pref("gfx.layerscope.enabled",                             false);
user_pref("gfx.direct2d.disabled",                              true);


// app switches //
user_pref("app.update.enabled",                                 false);
user_pref("app.update.auto",                                    false);
user_pref("app.update.disable_button.showUpdateHistory",        false);
user_pref("app.update.service.enabled",                         false);
user_pref("app.update.showInstalledUI",                         true);
user_pref("app.update.silent",                                  false);
user_pref("app.update.staging.enabled",                         false);


// etc switches //
// Preference name                                              Value //
user_pref("loop.enabled",                                       false);
user_pref("loop.server",                                        "");
user_pref("loop.logDomains",                                    false);
user_pref("gmp-eme-adobe.enabled",                              false);
user_pref("middlemouse.contentLoadURL",                         false);
user_pref("clipboard.autocopy",                                 false);
user_pref("keyword.enabled",                          false);
user_pref("general.buildID.override",                  "20100101");
user_pref("pdfjs.disabled",                                     true);
user_pref("pdfjs.enableWebGL",                                  false);
user_pref("layout.css.visited_links_enabled",                   false);
user_pref("breakpad.reportURL",                                 "");
user_pref("pageThumbs.enabled",                                 false);
user_pref("beacon.enabled",                                     false);
user_pref("layers.acceleration.disabled",                       true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

- `// comments` don't need another `//` at the end, but you can leave it there if you want.
- You don't need to repeat `// Preference name` and `value //` before every block of prefs; just one at the start should do.
- Version control. Using git will help you keep track of the changes you've made.
- You have a duplicate `dom.webnotifications.enabled`.
- You might want to put a comment next to each pref to say what each one does.
- You could restructure your code as:

  ```
  const prefs = {
    'browser.something': true,
    'browser.somehing_else': false,
    // etc.
  }

  for (let pref in prefs) {
    user_pref(pref, prefs[pref])
  }
  ```

  *if* you plan on later making it more complex, but the code's clear enough as it is.

And some comments about the prefs you're modifying:

- Disabling Firefox auto-update. Bad idea. New versions won't make it any less secure, and always contain [security fixes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox/). You can use an extended support release if you don't like updating; ESRs get security fixes every few weeks but only get new features / performance improvements etc. every year.
- Disabling JavaScript. Do it if you want, but it's better to use an addon like NoScript which gives you more control.
- Disabling notifications. It won't really improve security: sites have to ask for permission before being allowed to send you notifications.
- And lastly, just be careful. These prefs can nuke your browser if you press the wrong button :)

Comment: about the auto update: this was one of the mistakes I overlooked (which is the reason I wanted the code to be checked) and i will fix this.  About the javascript: i have chosen to turn it off because javascript is one of the most targeted platforms for malware, and even thoguh you are right about no script, it just feels wrong to leave java script turned on when making a security/privacy userscript. furthermore i have turned on notifications since in recent devlopments, notifications are used to insert malware into peoples computers. anyway thank you for reviewing. :)

Comment: (btw i am indeed trying to watch out with which prefs i use since you can break your browser with it. This is also one of the reasons i let the code be reviewed :)